# PHP Get ID from login

Tags: php, authentication

```
        if($row['usr'])
        {
            // If everything is OK login

            $_SESSION['usr']=$row['usr'];
            $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
            $id = $_GET['id'];
            $_SESSION['rememberMe'] = $_POST['rememberMe'];

            // Store some data in the session

            setcookie('tzRemember',$_POST['rememberMe']);
        }
        else $err[]='Wrong username and/or password!';
    }

    if($err)
    $_SESSION['msg']['login-err'] = implode('<br />',$err);
    // Save the error messages in the session
    $goHere = 'Location: /index2.php?id=' . $id;
    header($goHere);
    exit;
}
```

This currently gives an output in the url like `index2.php?id=` NOT `index2.php?id=105` or any integer really.

Anyone see why this UPDATED code isnt working?

Comment: Only one of $_GET or $_POST is set as result of a form-action. And like Trevor said beyond, you're not checking if the values are set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the value of `$id` only if `$row['usr']` is truthy. Move the `$id = $_GET['id'];` line outside the conditional.

Also, if you use a similar url to reach this page (`index1.php?123`) then `$_GET['id']` will *not* be set. You need to name the parameter (`index1.php?id=123`).

Comment: Can you show me code please? It looks as though, its just setting `index2.php?id= ` but NOT grabbing the ID value.

Comment: Do you have `?id=` set on *this* page? Do `print_r( $_GET )` to check that `$_GET['id']` is there. Did you move the `$id = $_GET['id'];` line outside the conditional?

Comment: No, I did not move it outside the conditional.

Comment: Its inside the if(){//in here}

Comment: Yeah, well, it will obviously not get set if the conditional is false. But it won't get set anyway if `$_GET['id']` is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure $id is even getting set? Mind you, a proper query string is formatted as 
`?key=value` where value is `$id`

Comment: technically speaking it could be correct, it creates a variable named $id with empty content....

Comment: True, but I am assuming he is looking to retrieve the value. :)

Comment: Have you checked if `$_GET['id']` or `$id` even contains any data?  Try echoing the variables and `exit` before the header call to test.

Answer (score 0):

Check $id is being set, it will only be set if the current page has somepage.php?id=1.  Are you sure it shouldn't be set to the session id?

I've had some issues with joining string within the header function so try this:

```
$go-here = 'Location: /index2.php?id=' . $id;
header($go-here);
```

Comment: How do I set it to the session ID? THe above code isnt working.

Comment: It doesn't make any difference where the string is concatenated.

Comment: I'm assuming $id = $_GET['id']; should be $id = $_SESSION['id'];

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you are not setting the ID properly (based on the code I can see...).  Wy not do the following?

```
$_SESSION['usr']=$row['usr'];
$_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
$id = $row['id'];
```

If you log a user in based on the ID from the DB row, then you can assign that row to $id as well as the session.  (Or better yet, don't even use $id, you can just use the session variable you just filled in with the user's id)...

Comment: @JohnPaul, did this one end up not working?  You unaccepted my answer? haha